# Visual studio makecert DES3 certificate

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, encryption, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I'm tring to create certificate via Visual Studio Command Prompt to meet the following requirements :

• A valid, (not expired), X.509 signing certifi cate must be used (e-mail certifi cate).

• RSA public key (signature) algorithms using key lengths of 1024 bits (or larger).
• Message Digest Algorithm must be SHA1-RSA.

• Encryption algorithm is DES3 (triple DES).

• Key usage must include digital signature (for signing fi les) and key encipherment (for encrypting
the fi les).

• Certifi cate (Public Key Only) should be exported in the following format

» .p7c (* PKCS7 cryptographic message syntax standard certifi cate)

» .cer (DER encoded binary X.509 Certifi cate)

» .cer (Base64 encoded X.509 Certifi cate)

I have tried as :

makecert.exe -sv TestCert.pvk -n “Test Cert” -a sha1 -len 1024 -sky 2 -eku 1.6.6.9.2.8.0.3.9 TestCert.cer -r

pvk2pfx.exe -pvk TestCert.pvk -spc TestCert.cer -pfx TestCert.pfx -po Test123$

I also am reading from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(v=vs.100).aspx 
but so far I have no luck. I have done someting valid one while ago but don't seem to remember how. Can someone give me some tips or example will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. The algorithm is named 3DES, not DES3.
2. The encryption algorithm can be applied at the stage of writing the private key to the disk in some format (like PEM or PFX). It's not a part of the certificate. This is why you can't find any option to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can you give me an example since i am reading also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550672(v=vs.85).aspx but cant still get my head around  it

Comment: @HristoAlexsiev I am not sure that I understand, what kind of example you are looking for. Certificate Generation is one thing, saving the private key to PFX or PEM are two other different things, saving the certificate with a public key to the DER-encoded file is simple, but one more different thing. All of those topics are covered here on Stack Overflow. MSDN is not the best place to look for this information, unfortunately.

Comment: Well maybe it's my fault for writing the topic wrong. Part of because i am bit confused myself.  Sorry for that. i will bore you with some more of the backstory. We have a partner witch works with partner and they have exchange encrypt and sign data. For witch you need certificate private key and public key for each  and they exchange public keys. So long time ago they ask me for certificate so i give them the 3. In time they have lost it due server problems. So they ask me for new one. Easy i said and make one as i make for sql encryption but well no. All that i get from them is :

Comment: that it is invalid and to check up writen requirements. So i went in to deadlock i have no idea what i am doing wrong or in what step. I have read some topics here and there but all seems legit :). So i'm trying to get second opinion how it should be done. :)

Comment: @HristoAlexsiev You should not and may not give them private keys. Each party must generate a keypair, keep the private key protected, and give the other party the public key. The procedure of doing this requires understanding of both PKI and security aspects of PKI deployment, and it can not be answered in a simple post. We recommend a couple of books to read on PKI topic: https://www.eldos.com/forum/read.php?FID=7&TID=1842